# Olark chat messanger integration with IOS application

Tags: ios, ios6

Hello friends,
              I'm currently developing a native mobile application for IOS. I need to integrate the Olark chat messanger with my application which is already integrated on my website synchronized with this app.
              Please let me know if anyone of you has an idea about how this can be achieved.

Comment: Their mobile support is terrible. I'm testing them now and I'm quite frustrated with their lack of commitment towards mobiles & tablets.

Answer (score 0):

There are no sdk's provided by Olark for iOS at the current time (8th Jan 2013).

I searched on Google and found a link : http://www.quora.com/Has-anyone-made-something-like-olark-for-mobile-iOS-yet . Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Yes.. I went through the link but didn't find any exact answer for the question I'm looking for. But I found this link http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4230700 it's given in that like Hipmob is Olark for mobile apps. Please share your thoughts on the same if you find it trustworthy. Thanks..